# Issues regarding Cucuber.json file which is used for Cucumber reports

Tags: json, maven, cucumber-jvm

I was trying to integrate my cucumber tests with maven-cucumber-reporting(from masterthought.net). I downloaded their Jenkins plugin and incorporated in my pom.xml file.
I have 2 tests in my eclipse project and when I ran these tests though maven it gets executed successfully. But, when I see my HTML report and also the cucumber.json , it displays details of only one test case.
I have been using Cucumber-JVM
Can you please let me know if I'm going wrong somewhere.

Thanks,
Prashanth

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two RunCukesTest files for your two tests? If so make sure that you are creating *unique* json files for each tests (Note Test1.json below, make sure you have that distinction for each of your tests). Otherwise they will be overwritten by each other and you will *only* see the results from your last test.

```
  @Cucumber.Options(format = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-report",
            "json-pretty:target/Test1.json" }, 
features = { "src/test/resources/features" })
```